# How can I choose 3 closest values out of 5 in a vector?

Tags: r

If I have a vector of values I only need some of, how can I choose the 3 closest ones?

```
c(14.493,14.588,15.175,14.934,14.981)
```

Comment: Please take the time to post a clearer question. What do you mean by 'closest'? To what? Do you mean in ranked order, closest to the mean, or the three values with the least differences from each other, to name just three interpretations of 'closest'? Without such information we can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean the 3 closest ones to a specific value, e.g. 15, use the following code:

```
data_5 <- c(14.493,14.588,15.175,14.934,14.981)
data_3 <- data_5[order(abs(data_5-15))[1:3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
closest3=function(x){
y=`is.na<-`(y<-abs(outer(x,x,"-")),y==0)
d=t(apply(y,2,function(i)which(rank(i,,"last")%in%c(1,2))))
e=cbind(1:length(x),d)
pos=e[which.min(colSums(abs(apply(e,1,function(j)diff(x[j]))))),]
setNames(x[pos],pos)
}
x=c(14.493,14.588,15.175,14.934,14.981)
closest3(x)
     3      4      5 
15.175 14.934 14.981
```

Another example:

```
x=c(1,0.9,5,4.5,12,0.8)#We expect 1,0.9 and 0.8
closest3(e)
  1   2   6 
1.0 0.9 0.8
```

Comment: Sorry,
I meant how can I choose the 3 closest to each other. Something like outliers only not based on mean or median. So if I have a list of vectors I can quickly get rid of edge values

Comment: Look at the code again. When you give it a vector it will give you the three values that are closest to each other. I am not using mean nor median. I am using the distance. For example a vector like 1,6,9,3,17,87,55,2.we see that the three closest are 1,3,2. Not using statistical methods.. now the function above will indeed give you 1,3,2 as the results meaning it does what the question asks

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a go